# Coffeescript if/else issue

Tags: if-statement, coffeescript

How can i write this line of code in Coffeescript? Thank's

```
    window.scrollY >= origOffsetY ? navbar.classList.add('navbar-fixed-top') : 
                                    navbar.classList.remove('navbar-fixed-top');
```

I try this, but doesn't work.

```
if window.scrollY >= origOffsetY then navbar.classList.add('navbar-fixed-top') else navbar.classList.remove('navbar-fixed-top')
```

Comment: Works for me (the CoffeeScript you provided compiles to the exact JS you provided).

Comment: Ok, thank's, maybe it's my compiler.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your coffeescript compiles to :

```
if (window.scrollY >= origOffsetY) {
  navbar.classList.add('navbar-fixed-top');
} else {
  navbar.classList.remove('navbar-fixed-top');
}
```

This seems pretty OK for me.